# Not able to create Outlook add-in for work account only

Tags: outlook-addin, appsource

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in for the Appsource store (https://appsource.microsoft.com/). 
But when the app appears in the store, users are required to switch to their personal account to acquire the app.

I want business users to be able to get my add-in with switching to a personal account. Where and how is this controlled? - I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, purchasing add-in licenses is currently only available via Microsoft Accounts. 
Users will be able to acquire trial licenses with their O365 Accounts via the Outlook store, but they will have to swap to MSA for the full purchase. 
If you're looking to handle purchase for O365 accounts, I'd recommend reading our GTM [guidance](https://dev.office.com/blogs/gtm-how-to-monetize-with-office-add-ins-and-apps) on freemium setups.